# Jquery getting the correct value based on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I cannot get this simple code to work. I want to get the value from the data attribute and based on that pass it to the alert

http://jsfiddle.net/btL9C/

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
     var section_list = $('.section').data('section_list');

     if ($(this).hasClass(section_list+"_list")) {          
         alert(section_list);
     }
});
```

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-section_list = "1" class="section 1_list">
<input type="checkbox" data-section_list = "2" class="section 2_list">
<input type="checkbox" data-section_list = "3" class="section 3_list">
```

How can I get the alert to display the corresponding value of data-section_list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {

    var section_list = $(this).data().section_list;

   if ($(this).hasClass(section_list+"_list")) {          
        alert(section_list);
   }
});
```

Comment: using 'this' in my actual code get's undefined even though the set up is the same as the one I posted

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/embkay06/wnM7h/) i have did the same thing. it seems to be working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `$(this)` reference while fetching the `data` from the current element,

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    var section_list = $(this).data('section_list');
    if ($(this).hasClass(section_list + "_list")) {
        alert(section_list);
    }
}); //-- You have missed to mention the close parenthesis here.
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/btL9C/1/)

Comment: @Downvote: Can you please specify the reason for your vote..? so that i could fix the mistakes that i made..

Comment: @sudharsan .it s comedy dont take any serious .just fun

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy and bala please delete all comment which you are posted

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/btL9C/2/)**

1. Missing paranthesis last line - `change` function.
2. Also use `$(this)` to get data.

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
         var section_list = $(this).data('section_list');

         if ($(this).hasClass(section_list+"_list")) {          
             alert(section_list);
         }
    });  // <-- Missing
});
```

Comment: 1. my mistake copying. 2. this gets me undefined value for my actual code which is similar set up

Comment: @Gadgetster, have you included jQuery reference?

Answer (score 2):

you need to get current clicked element data attribute by using `this` currently you are getting using `$(".section")` which will not give desired output as there are multiple elements on page with this class:

change:

```
var section_list = $(".section").data('section_list');
```

to:

```
var section_list = $(this).data('section_list'); //<--- gets current cliked element data attribute
```

Your code will look like:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
     var section_list = $(this).data('section_list');

     if ($(this).hasClass(section_list+"_list")) {          
         alert(section_list);
     }
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/HL2bL/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the attribute of the element you are clicking on

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
     var section_list = $(this).attr('data-section_list');

     if ($(this).hasClass(section_list+"_list")) {          
         alert(section_list);
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people unecessarily try to downvote for no reason. I'm trying to contribute too.

Comment: it is wrong man - $(this).attr('data-section_list');
but i didn't put downvote for you thanks

Comment: why is that, is the attr (http://api.jquery.com/attr/) depreciated? I know the data function is used to pass info that is not necessarily set as an attribute

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
use this instead .section after change function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
     var section_list = $(this).data('section_list');

     if ($(this).hasClass(section_list+"_list")) {          
         alert(section_list);  
     }
});  
});  
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btL9C/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) alert($(this).attr("data-section_list"));
});
```